# How to test the working of flutter package?

Tags: flutter

What would be the best practice to test the working of flutter package?

Recently I developed a Flutter package and I am testing its functionality by creating another flutter application and importing it to there, in this way I have to deal with two projects. Is there any method to do all it in the same project like android native development?

`example/` directory contains only example.dart which is not runable? Any suggestion ?

Comment: You can put whatever you want in the example folder. Even a complete flutter project

Comment: Thanks man , I googled more and found that Flutter official packages are based on same procedure.

Comment: @ShahzadAkram can you share that link

Comment: I implemented this at here, https://github.com/shah-xad/flutter_tex

Comment: Did you find any way to test the flutter package without creating other project?

Answer (score 8):

Answer based off of Shahzad's [flutter_tex package](https://github.com/shah-xad/flutter_tex), and thanks to Remi's suggestion.

As mentioned, one way to test a package in Flutter is to create a Flutter app within the "Example" directory. In this app, list the following in the pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  your_package_name:
    path: ../
```

As shown, you specify your package's path, which is the level above the "Example" folder the test app resides in.